# Is it reasonable to fudge the iterator category if my container falls between two of the existing values?

Tags: c++, iterator, random-access

I have a rope container using a self-balancing order-statistic tree as its underlying storage (each tree node containing a variable but in general fairly numerous elements of the rope, for example if storing chars the tree nodes are likely to hold ~4000 elements).

Is it reasonable to assign the rope iterators the std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category even though the +, +=, -, -=, etc operations are actually logarithmic complexity (in terms of distance from the current position)? If the new position lies within the current tree node (which should be much more frequent than larger jumps) then the operation is in fact O(1)as required by random access, it is only when needing to step along the tree that the true O(1) complexity is lost. However in all cases it is much better than O(n) as using bidirectional would imply.

I could, of course, make up my own category tag but I would then need to specialize the various free-standing algorithm functions to take advantage.

Perhaps this is an opinion question that is not really suitable to SO but I am still curious what people think about this issue.

Comment: You say the logarithmic case is rare. Maybe you can mathematically prove that the amortized complexity is still constant?

Comment: I would be confident saying the amortized complexity is constant if the increment would always change by 1 but the rope is being used in a text editor and so the distance is up to the user (by grapheme, word, sentence, paragraph page or even a percentage position of the entire document). By character is most likely, not sure if word or line is next most common.

Comment: By the way, O(lg n) is not "much better" than implied by O(n), as big-O notation is an upper limit. Something that is O(lg n) is also O(n). It's also O(n^3) for that matter.

Comment: @JaMiT What........

Comment: @JaMiT: Given that my typical envisioned usage is a container of several million elements I would say that lg N and N are a fair bit different.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica It is a matter of interpretation. Not all algorithms that are `O(n)` are worse than all algorithms that are `O(ln n)`, but there are some `O(n)` algorithms that are worse than any `O(ln n)` algorithm. One should use `Theta(n)` here instead of `O(n)` to make both statements true. `O` is commonly misused to also imply a lower bound anyway, though, so this might be a bit pedantic.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes, `lg N` and `N` are different. You are missing two key points in my comment. First, I used [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), not simply the functions; `O(lg N)`, not simply `lg N`. Second, the relation is not symmetric. An algorithm that is `O(lg N)` is also `O(N)`, but an algorithm that is `O(N)` is not necessarily `O(lg N)`. To give an example: `lg N < N` for sufficiently large `N`, so `lg N` is `O(N)`. However, there is no constant `M` such that `N < M*lg N` for sufficiently large `N`, so `N` is not `O(lg N)`.

Comment: Yes, it can be pedantic to emphasize the difference between big-O (upper limit) and big-theta (asymptotically similar) notations, but I think it's relevant to this question. Nowhere is there specified a requirement that a bidirectional iterator **must** be slow when adding an integer (if it supports that syntax). Complexity requirements for C++ cannot be expressed using big-theta notation because faster than required is allowed; the pedantic meaning of big-O notation is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are using a container from a library. The library's documentation claims the container's iterators satisfy the requirements of a random access iterator. Your program has performance issues, which you trace back to those iterators' increment operator being O(lg n) instead of O(1). Would you feel justified in complaining / filing a bug report? Probably.

Do you want to write code that others will complain about? Probably not. Your mileage may vary, but it is usually better to understate performance than overstate it. Few people complain that computations are too fast.

Comment: And if they do, one can simply add a delay and reduce it in the next few updates. At least I read that somewhere... ;-)